# Как получить сумму цифр из строки?

Tags: php

Имеется строка `"1111111111"`. Как провести операцию сложения её цифр 1+1+1+1+... ?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так

```
array_sum(str_split($x));
```

Answer (score 3):

Если там только единицы, то

```
strlen('111111111'); // 9
```

(шутка)

Comment: В каждой шутке доля шутки. В задаче с поставленным условием отличное оптимизированное решение )

Answer (score 2):

```
echo array_sum(str_split($str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно разделить строку на массив и цепляться к символам, как к его элементам.

```
$arr = str_split("1111111"); // разбивает строку на массив символов
$result = 0;
foreach ($arr as $value) { // проходимся по массиву
     $result += intval($value); // и суммируем результат
}
echo $result; // выводим результат
```

Можно немного улучшить. К примеру во входной строке есть шанс встретить буквы вместо цифр, тогда:

```
   $arr = str_split("1111xsqd11");
   $result = 0;
   foreach ($arr as $value) {
            // если $value это число, то прибавим его значение, если нет - прибавим ноль.
            $result += is_numeric($value) ? intval($value) : 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант - протись по строке, принимая каждый символ за цифру.

```
while ($i--) { 
    $result+= intval($a{$i}); 
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "1111111111";
// Разбиваем на массив (по одному символу) и сводим к одному значению через array_reduce
$total = array_reduce(str_split($str), function($ac, $e){$ac += (int) $e; return $ac;});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '1111111111';
$sum = 0;
do {
    $sum += $string % 10;
}
while ($string = (int) $string / 10);
echo $sum; //Выведет 10
```

Можете попробовать с другими значениями: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e1b2d522eb1e9402ba727d24112abd2a59879a63

Comment: А переполнение?